# Read post requests from computer

Tags: java, http, post

i'm trying to write a java program to read everything I post to a certain website (facebook in this case), I'm trying to make a program to save my ongoing chat to text, I can find the POST in fiddler, but how do I read it in java? I didn't try anything so far because I don't know where to start, and I can't search because I don't know what to search for, is there a better way to do it ? thanks

Comment: This will be OS specific. You'd need a JNI/JNA hook on a OS specific library (such as a DLL file in Windows). Your first step would be figuring what OS you'd like to target and what OS specific library you need to hook on by JNI/JNA by reading the OS specific developer documentation (e.g. at MSDN in case of Windows). By the way, is it legal what you're trying to do after all?

Comment: Or another, easier and totally legal idea would be to create an HTTP proxy in Java, configure your browser to use it, and log whatever requests you want whenever you want.

Comment: That would indeed be easier if it's for personal use only.

Comment: @Max Oh right, traffic sniffing is not legal, but man-in-the-middle is :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're really looking for something like network traffic sniffer written in Java you'll need to start with researching [Jpcap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/).

You could try their samples, they seem to have a code for Java [Tcpdump](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/samples.html) implementation ready to use.

But listening to traffic is a hack and not a solution, thus should be used episodically and not in production. And if it's not in production why bother with Java and not use command line tools like [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/)?